# MYSQL joining based on two different parameters

Tags: mysql, join, alias

**My Code:**

```
SELECT eval_table.form, teacher_table.name AS Subject, teacher_table.name0 AS Author  
FROM `eval_table`
JOIN `teacher_table` ON eval_table.subj = teacher_table.user_id;
```

**Result:**

| form | Subject | Author |
| --- | --- | --- |
| internal review | John Doe | John Doe |

My problem is that I need to simultaneously `JOIN teacher_table ON eval_table.auth = teacher_table.user_id;` but only for `teacher_table.name0` to get the following result:

| form | Subject | Author |
| --- | --- | --- |
| internal review | John Doe | Jane Doe |

`teacher_table.name0` is a virtual copy of `teacher_table.name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a second join to the `teacher_table` and then return the result as indicated.

The following SQL gives an example of this:

```
SELECT  et.form,
        tt1.name AS Subject,
        tt2.name0 AS Author  
  FROM  eval_table et
    INNER JOIN teacher_table tt1 ON tt1.user_id = et.subj
    INNER JOIN teacher_table tt2 ON tt2.user_id = et.auth;
```

In this example, the first join to `teacher_table` is on `user_id = et.subj` as per the existing join and uses the alias `tt1`.  The second join is on `user_id = et.auth` and uses the alias `tt2`.

Using the method above you can make multiple joins to the same table on different columns.  Using an *alias* for the table names (i.e. `et`, `tt1`, and `tt2`) makes it possible to use the same table more than once but refer to them uniquely in the output.

Note that the SQL is untested but should give an indication as to how to proceed.

Comment: Thank you very much this works perfectly. As a quick sub question; since `name` and `name0` are identical columns can `name` be called twice with 2 different aliases to  obtain the same result as using `name` and `name0`?

Comment: @j__carlson You're welcome.  Yes it can indeed - you can refer to `tt1.name` and `tt2.name` and they will both be selected for the output.  Using an output column alias (like you have with `Subject` and `Author`) is a good idea in that situation as the columns have identical names

Answer (score 0):

You want to alias the table, allowing you to work with it as if it were a different one:

```
SELECT evaluations.form, teachers.name, evaluators.name 
FROM evaluations 
JOIN teachers 
  ON evaluations.subject = teachers.name
JOIN teachers AS evaluators 
  ON evaluations.evaluator = evaluators.name;
```

As an aside, I’ve taken the liberty to slightly standardize the naming scheme. Use plurals or singulars, capitalize or don’t, but keep it consistent. And tables don’t need _table suffixes. They know what they are.

Comment: I appreciate the advice on naming convention. I have adjusted my table and ran your code with the following result: `Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'John Doe'`. Any insight would be appreciated.